# How Add Piezo Buzz to Pong Sketch

Tags: c++, sketch, piezo

I am junior high teacher teaching students how to program using Arduino. I know the basics of programing but the students wanted to program a game which is a little above my skill set. I am using the following sketch (http://www.itopen.it/arduino-pong-with-8x8-led-matrix-and-max7219/) to introduce them to programing games. Thanks to this site I understand most of the code. However I would like to add a line of code that will make a piezo buzzer buzz every time the "ball" hits the pad. I think the code should look something like the code bellow, but I am not sure if it is correct or where I would put it.

```
#define buz 8 // number of pin buzzer connected to 
     if (HIT_CENTER || HIT_RIGHT || HIT_LEFT) {
        digitalWrite(buz, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digiralWrite(buz, LOW);
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The condition `HIT_CENTER || HIT_RIGHT || HIT_LEFT` will always be true.  (All three of those `HIT_` values are non-zero constants.)

Instead, you need to test if `getHit()` is non-zero.  (To see this, search the sketch for occurrences of `HIT_RIGHT` or `HIT_LEFT`.)

The sketch sets up an event timer (via `ball_timer = timer.every(BALL_DELAY, moveBall);` in `setup()`) so that ball position will update every 200 ms.  The `loop()` sequence is: Use `timer.update()` to service timer events.  Use `setPad()` to read the paddle position.  Use `drawGame()` to update the game picture. Somehow use `checkLoose()` to see if game is over.  Use `delay(GAME_DELAY)` to wait 10 ms.

Given that structure of `loop()`, throwing in a 100 ms delay to wait for a buzzer would mess up the game play.  You could turn on the buzzer and set up a timer event for turning it off, each time the ball hits the paddle.

More straightforwardly, since a 10 ms beep is likely to be adequately long, you could test for a hit just before `delay(GAME_DELAY)`, and always turn the buzzer off just after that delay.  In other words, before the delay say:
`if (getHit()) digitalWrite(buz, HIGH);` and after the delay say `digitalWrite(buz, LOW);`.

This supposes that writing HIGH to `buz` turns on the buzzer and that writing LOW turns it off.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**
here is what i would have done is use this code snippet we can get the state of HIT,,,if it is not equal to HIT_NONE ,buzz it

```
 #define buz 8 
 if(getHit()!=HIT_NONE){
    digitalWrite(buz, HIGH);
    delay(10);
    digitalWrite(buz, LOW);
    }
```

This is the simpler version where in delay is small,Beaware using delay will completely halt processor operation ,buttons ,joystick serial ports etc everything will be halted.

**Method 2:With Flexible Delay**

```
  #define buz 8
  unsigned long previousMillis = 0; 
  const long interval = 200;   /////Specify the delay you want here
  void loop()
   {
     unsigned long currentMillis = millis();  //start timer
     /*
         Remaining Code Is Left As It Is
     */
   }



       ///////////Code Snippet Without Using Delay
   if(getHit()!=HIT_NONE){
   digitalWrite(buz, HIGH);
   if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) 
        {
            previousMillis = currentMillis;
            digitalWrite(buz, LOW);
        }
   }
```

But where to add these functions???
Use ***getHit()*** to implement ,,,just like below

```
  int getHit() {
  if(yball != 6 || xball < xpad || xball > xpad + PADSIZE){
    return HIT_NONE;          //returns in case of hit failure so no 
                              // buzzer ring
     } 
        digitalWrite(buz, HIGH);    //If it has not returned yet makes
        delay(10);                  //sure that it is a successful hit
        digitalWrite(buz, LOW);     //buzzer ring
  if(xball == xpad + PADSIZE / 2){
    return HIT_CENTER;
     }
   return xball < xpad + PADSIZE / 2 ? HIT_LEFT : HIT_RIGHT;
 }
```

yet again u can replace those 3 lines with below one to be more flexible

```
digitalWrite(buz, HIGH);
if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) 
     {
         previousMillis = currentMillis;
         digitalWrite(buz, LOW);
     }
}
```

hope this helps.